# Java Priority Queue - No initial capacity, but passed compiler?

Tags: java, priority-queue

Used the following code to instantiate a priority queue. 
  Didn't expect it'd pass the complier, since the [official doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) says pq takes 2 args: initial capacity and comparator. But the code compiled and had no run-time errors. Any explanation?

`PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator)`

```
 PriorityQueue<ListNode> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(
     new Comparator<ListNode>(){
        public int compare(ListNode n1, ListNode n2) { 
        return n1.val - n2.val; 
     }
 });
```

Comment: See the javadoc for Java8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html . There is a matching constructor.

Comment: You're looking at the documentation for Java 7 - I suspect you're using Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple constructors.

You used one that only requires a `Comparator` instance :

```
/**
 * Creates a {@code PriorityQueue} with the default initial capacity and
 * whose elements are ordered according to the specified comparator.
 *
 * @param  comparator the comparator that will be used to order this
 *         priority queue.  If {@code null}, the {@linkplain Comparable
 *         natural ordering} of the elements will be used.
 * @since 1.8
 */
public PriorityQueue(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
    this(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY, comparator);
}
```

EDIT:

This constructor was added in Java 8, which is why it is not mentioned in the link you provided. The [Java 8 version includes the new constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Comparator-).

Answer (score 0):

The constructor with a single comparator is defined in Java 8 (but is not defined in Java 7).

So the explanation is that you are looking at the Java 7 API but using the Java 8.